# React-Leaflet Style doesn't load in <GeoJson/>

Tags: react-leaflet-v4

I am using a codesandox file which is using a GeoJson from React Leaflet.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-geojson-forked-w8stw6?file=/package.json

This exact code with the same package version doesnt work when I run it locally. By doesnt work I mean the color layers shown in codesandbox doesnt get rendered when running on Local.

Can someone please help me out!